# Opening a PDF document when clicking a button

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, button

I am trying to create an app for my family restaurant in swift. I currently have a button that you click on that takes you too a webviewer page of our menu. I want to make the menu with in the app so it does not redirect to safari.

Basically what I want to do is click a button and it opens the menu pdf within the app instead safari.

The code that I use too open the PDF in a browser:

```
    @IBAction func menu(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let url = NSURL(string:"http://nebula.wsimg.com/db5e994c02db104ea89bdf6e59550490?AccessKeyId=895454CA4A1E296ED3E3&disposition=0&alloworigin=1") {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried to do to enable opening the PDF, and where exactly do you have a problem.

Comment: @Leo Dabus I am writing a iOS app on OSX.

Comment: You can use QLPreviewController to preview your pdf (also share / print if needed)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/

Comment: @p4sh4 I am new too swift, in face I just started using it yesterday and the only solution I could find right now was too open the PDF in safari. But this is the code that I have to do that:

Comment: If you would like to preview it inside your app you can use QLPreviewControllerDataSource with your view controller, and add the required methods (numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController, previewItemAtIndex)

Comment: @LeoDabus could you guide me on how I could code that, I am really new to swift.

Comment: @p4sh4 I have added the code that I use too open the website in to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QLPreviewController to preview your pdf but it needs to be a local resource or downloaded from the web prior to previewing:

**Swift 3 or later**

```
import UIKit
import QuickLook

class ViewController: UIViewController, QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
    let preview = QLPreviewController()
    func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
        return Bundle.main.url(forResource: "menu", withExtension: "pdf")!
            as QLPreviewItem
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // set preview data source
        preview.dataSource = self
        // set current item index (only one = 0)
        preview.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0
    }
    @IBAction func showMenu(sender: UIButton) {
        present(preview, animated: true) {
            // code
        }
    }
}
```