# warning: attempt to present whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, uidocumentinteraction, uivewcontroller

I have a UITabView in UIViewController, all tab items are linked to other UIViewControllers. I have written a swift code of downloading a file through internet. when I select second tabItem, this code runs well, it downloads and previews the downloaded file, Then when I click on first tabItem and then again click on second tabItem; file downloads well but it doesn't show any preview instead xCode gives me a warning message: 
What I want is download file and preview file both should work when I again click on the second tabItem. whatever the code is.

> warning: attempt to present QLPreviewController on KPIViewController  whose view is not in the window hierarchy

I have found many solutions on the internet but it didn't work

first solution says to use

```
 let viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(viewer, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but this function

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(viewer, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

do not accept 
 `UIDocumentInteractionController`

second solution says to override the existing `presentViewController` function to

```
override func presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {

        let APP_DELEGATE = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
        var presentedModalVC:UIViewController = (APP_DELEGATE!.window?!.rootViewController?.presentedViewController)!

        if presentedModalVC == true {

            while((presentedModalVC.presentedViewController) != nil){

                presentedModalVC = presentedModalVC.presentedViewController!
            }
            presentedModalVC.presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: nil)
        }
        else{
            APP_DELEGATE?.window!!.rootViewController?.presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

I tried this but it also needs a UIViewController in its parameters where I have `UIDocumentInteractionController`
I know these function cannot accept `UIDocumentInteractionController` type viewController.

here is my whole swift code:

```
//  KPIViewController.swift
//  download
//
//  Created by me on 15/03/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 me. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class KPIViewController: UIViewController,UITabBarDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var tabBar1: UITabBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var login_Item: UITabBarItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var QAreport_Item: UITabBarItem!


    @IBOutlet weak var KpiWebView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    var downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask!
    var backgroundSession: NSURLSession!

    var downloadReport:Bool!

    var AuditCodeOfDashboardCell:String?
    var AuditCodeForPDF:String?
    let isDirectory: ObjCBool = false


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.progressView.hidden = true
        downloadReport = false

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.tabBar1.delegate = self

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        self.progressView.hidden = true

        downloadReport = false

        let backgroundSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("backgroundSession")
        backgroundSession = NSURLSession(configuration: backgroundSessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)


        var requestURL = NSURL!()
        var request = NSURLRequest!()
        // loading data from web

        if AuditCodeOfDashboardCell != nil{
            print(self.AuditCodeOfDashboardCell)
            requestURL = NSURL(string:“my URL string&\(AuditCodeOfDashboardCell)”)
            request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
            AuditCodeForPDF = AuditCodeOfDashboardCell
            AuditCodeOfDashboardCell = nil

        }else{
            requestURL = NSURL(string:“my URL string”)
            request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        }
        KpiWebView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {

        print("selected tabItem: \(item.tag)")
        switch (item.tag) {
        case 1:
            let loginVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginViewController") as! LoginView
            presentViewController(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

            break
        case 2:
            if AuditCodeForPDF != nil{

                downloadReport = true

                let url = NSURL(string: “my URL string&\(AuditCodeForPDF)”)!
                urlToDownload = url
            }

//                if let resultController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(“2”) as? QAReportViewController {

//                    presentViewController(resultController, animated: true, completion: nil)
//                }

            break

        default:
            break
        }

        if downloadReport == true{

            let url = NSURL(string: “my URL string&\(AuditCodeForPDF)”)!

            downloadTask = backgroundSession.downloadTaskWithURL(url)
            self.progressView.hidden = false
            downloadTask.resume()
            downloadReport = false

        }
    }

    // - - Handling download file-  - - - - - -  - -

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
        downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask,
        didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL){

            let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
            let documentDirectoryPath:String = path.first!
            let fileManager = NSFileManager()
            var destinationURLForFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingString("/Report.pdf"))

            if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(destinationURLForFile.path!){
                //                showFileWithPath(destinationURLForFile.path!)
                do{
                    try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(destinationURLForFile.path!)
                    destinationURLForFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingString("/Report.pdf"))
                }catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }

            do {
                try fileManager.moveItemAtURL(location, toURL: destinationURLForFile)
                // show file
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                    self.showFileWithPath(destinationURLForFile.path!)
                })
            }catch{
                print("An error occurred while moving file to destination url")
            }

    }

    func showFileWithPath(path: String){
        let isFileFound:Bool? = NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path)
        if isFileFound == true{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                let viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))
                viewer.delegate = self
                viewer.presentPreviewAnimated(true)
            })

        }
    }
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession,
        downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask,
        didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64,
        totalBytesWritten: Int64,
        totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64){
            progressView.setProgress(Float(totalBytesWritten)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite), animated: true)
    }

    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController{
        return self

    }
    func documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {
        print("document preview ends")

    }

}
```

I cannot find any proper solution that solve my problem. I am new with swift
please anyone on help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the code to present QLPreviewController?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34148055/2303865

Comment: Thanks Leo Dabus; but this takes file path only from NSBundle where I have documentDirectoryPath.

Comment: Hi Leo Dabus; I found a way to use DocumentDirectoryPath instead of NSBundle, but still I got the same error. now I have edited my question with my code file. kindly provide me some help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`UIDocumentInteractionController` is not kind of `UIViewController`. So you cannot present an `UIDocumentInteractionController` with `presentViewController:` method.

Checkout https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/

You can presenting a document preview or options menus with UIDocumentInteractionController.

Comment: yes I know it cannot be presented but I want to preview my download file when I again click on second TabItem. where it gives me a warning: Warning: Attempt to present <QLPreviewController: 0x160b67fc0> on <QUONDA.KPIViewController: 0x160b00670> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!