# Cannot access a file in a bundle

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, bundle

I experience a problem getting path/url for a file in a bundle. Here is a code I use

```
@IBOutlet weak var testWebView: UIWebView!

private func setText() {

if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "theory", ofType: "pdf") {
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    testWebView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
 }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
  // setText()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)
setText()
}
```

the file theory.pdf is in the main bundle (no subfolders etc.)
I tried many ways discussed here, like copying with Create Group/Create folder Reference, etc. - nothing helped.
webView is set in StoryBoard.

Comment: Is the Target Membership set of the file? Is the spelling correct (case matters)? By the way, use `Bundle.main.url(forResource:withExtension:)`, (`URL`) and `URLRequest` to avoid the ugly bridge casts.

Comment: To open a local file resource with WKWebView you should use loadfileurl  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414973-loadfileurl

Comment: To preview a pdf https://stackoverflow.com/a/34148055/2303865

Comment: What is the Target Membership set...? spelling is absolutely correct (just copy-pasted the name. Bundle.main.url did not work as well.

Comment: the method in stackoverflow - did not work, probably the same reason, bundle.main.url returns nil. wrt WKWebView - I am not using that :-( mine is simple UIWebView of UIKit.

Comment: Select the file in the navigation bar and press ⌥⌘1 . The Target Membership checkbox must be checked. Of course the `Bundle.main.url...` method does not solve the issue but it's the recommended API to get an URL directly (without the line `URL(fileURLWith....`)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to show a PDF I strongly suggest to use a `UIDocumentInteractionController`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var documentInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController?

    private func setText() {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "theory", ofType: "pdf") {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            let controller = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url)
            controller.delegate = self
            controller.presentPreview(animated: true)
            documentInteractionController = controller
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewDidAppear(animated)
         setText()
    }

}
```

Also you need to implement the `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate`:

```
extension ViewController: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
         return self
    }

}
```

Comment: This will actually open another app. I would recommend using QLPreviewController or PDFKit (iOS 11+)

Comment: Thank you, sure this would be better, but my problem is that path receives nil from Bundle.main.url/path. I could not get through that line of code. :-(

Comment: iOS is case sensitive, so the file must match exactly theory.pdf. After adding the file to the project you need to make sure that is copied on the bundle when the bundle is packaged. You can verify this by going to the target Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources. The file must be on the list. If is not there you can add it using the + or by selecting it from the Project Navigator and check it on the Target Membership.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys. I sorted out the problem. Instead of drag-n-droping the PDF into the bundle, I right-clicked at Project Navigator and selected add Files to...
Thereafter on uploaded file right-clicked again and select add....
Finally it worked. Thanks again. Now I will be experimenting with your proposals.